# Populating Outlook body, retaining formatting, from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook, html-email

I convert a sheet in Excel to PDF, then attach it to an email, then populate the email with some default text but not send it. That way the sales person can finalize anything that varies from the default.

The email is created and the body is populated but formatting is lost.

I tried posting the formatted text to an IE instance, where it formats, then copying it from there into Outlook (dug up a reference somewhere about using that as a workaround).

```
Option Explicit

Sub QuotePDF()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim sFirstName As String, sFullFileName As String, sFileName As String, sFileLocation As String, tempPDFFileName As String
Dim tempPSFileName As String, tempPDFRawFileName As String, sTo As String, sSubject As String, sBody As String
Dim sSender As String, sActivePrinter As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim Mail_Object, Email_Subject, o As Variant

sFirstName = Left(Sheets("Quote Step 1").Range("g6").Value, InStr(Sheets("Quote Step 1").Range("g6").Value, " ") - 1)
sSender = " "
sTo = Sheets("Quote Step 1").Range("g9").Value
sSubject = "SUBJECT GOES HERE"
sBody = sFirstName & ", " & Chr(13) & Chr(13) & "BODY GOES HERE " & Chr(13) & Chr(13) & "Regards, " & Chr(13) & sSender'these formating characters get lost when passed to the function but this was one method I tried to use so left it in while sorting through things
sActivePrinter = "Adobe PDF"
sFileLocation = Environ$("temp") & "\" & "PDF Name.pdf"
sFullFileName = CreatePDF(Source:=Sheets("Quote Step 2").Range("A1:H51"), FixedFilePathName:=sFileLocation, OverwriteIfFileExist:=True, OpenPDFAfterPublish:=False)
    If sFullFileName <> "" Then
'this function below MailPDF(FileNamePDF As String, StrTo As String, StrCC As String, StrBCC As String, StrSubject As String, Signature As Boolean, Send As Boolean, StrBody As String) - signature is a display/dont display variable
        sFullFileName = MailPDF(sFullFileName, sTo, "", "", sSubject, True, False, sBody)
    Else
        MsgBox "Can not create PDF."
    End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Function CreatePDF(Source As Object, FixedFilePathName As String, OverwriteIfFileExist As Boolean, OpenPDFAfterPublish As Boolean) As String
    Dim FileFormatstr As String
    Dim Fname As Variant

    If FixedFilePathName = "" Then
            FileFormatstr = "PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf"
            Fname = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("", filefilter:=FileFormatstr, Title:="Create PDF")
        If Fname = False Then Exit Function
    Else
        Fname = FixedFilePathName
    End If

    If OverwriteIfFileExist = False Then
        If Dir(Fname) <> "" Then Exit Function
    End If

    On Error Resume Next
    Source.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:=Fname, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=OpenPDFAfterPublish
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Dir(Fname) <> "" Then CreatePDF = Fname
End Function

Function MailPDF(FileNamePDF As String, StrTo As String, StrCC As String, StrBCC As String, StrSubject As String, Signature As Boolean, Send As Boolean, StrBody As String)
    Dim OutApp As Object, OutMail As Object, Ie As Object
    Dim sBody1 As String, sBody2 As String, sBody3 As String, sBody4 As String
    Dim s1stSpace As String

    sBody1 = Left(StrBody, InStr(StrBody, " "))'this approach where I can give him 4 cells to enter text into and format however he wants is prefered to hard coding text into the VBA

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        If Signature = True Then .Display
        .To = StrTo
        .CC = StrCC
        .BCC = StrBCC
        .Subject = StrSubject
        .HTMLBody = "<P STYLE='font-family:Arial;font-size:11'>Hi " & sBody1 & "<br>" & .HTMLBody' this was not working at all for me as I mentioned above - formatting was getting processed in passing to the function - so I moved it here. It was better but the arial formatting wouldn't stick
        .Attachments.Add FileNamePDF
        If Send = True Then
            .Send
        Else
            .Display
        End If

    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot concatenate 2 HTML strings and expect the result to be a valid HTML string.

Look for the position of the `"<body"` string, find the position of the next `">"`(this way you can support body elements with attributes), then insert your data there.

Comment: So I would change this? 
'    .HTMLBody = "<P STYLE='font-family:Arial;font-size:11'>Hi " & sBody1 & "<br>" & .HTMLBody' '

Comment: No, you are missing my point - your code is NewHTMLBody = YourHTMLData + OldHTMLBody. The concatenation part is the problem. You need to read the existing HTMLBody into a variable, find the appropriate point where your data needs to be inserted, insert your data, set the HTMLBody property.

Comment: AH! Thank you for spelling that out for me. Rough week apparently. I'll try that route out now!